# AcrCloud Not able to upload audio file

Tags: acrcloud

Getting below error even we are passing title in request body

```
{   
  "name": "Unprocessable entity",
  "message": "Lack field:title",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 422 
}
```

Any Help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill up the title field. Which is required.

please refer to this example code

https://github.com/acrcloud/webapi_example/tree/master/RESTful%20service

Comment: You should include the relevant example in  your answer. There is no guarantee that this repo will be around in 5 years when this question still is.